# Is $C^3$ homemorphic to $R^6$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Is there any simple approach to prove or disprove that $C^3$ is homeomorphic to $R^6$  in Euclidean Topology?

Can anyone give me a hint? I  know Topology till compactness.

Comment: Are you aware that $\Bbb C$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: ?? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: yesssss@HagenvonEitzen

Comment: @cmi: with that information, this problem should not be terribly difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{C}^3&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^6\\(z_1,z_2,z_3)&\mapsto&(\operatorname{Re}z_1,\operatorname{Im}z_1,\operatorname{Re}z_2,\operatorname{Im}z_2,\operatorname{Re}z_3,\operatorname{Im}z_3).\end{array}$$It is a continuous bijection, right?! Can you prove that the inverse is continuous too?

Comment: I got you...If I try by the following way, Would I be correct?  $I : R^2 \times R^2 \times R^2    \to  C  \times C \times C$ is homeomorphic as $I:R^2 \to C$ is homeomorphic.

Comment: @cmi That would be correct indeed.